# How to access webpage (served by Pycharm License Server, on Ubuntu) on 8080 over LAN

Tags: pycharm, licensing, ubuntu-16.04, lan, ports

I am attempting to set up a [PyCharm License Server](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/license_server/getting_started.html) on my LAN.

I have an Ubuntu 16.04 server, `hightower` set up to do this.  I've installed the license server, and it appears to be successfully running on 8080:

```
admin@hightower:/opt/jetbrains$ sudo bin/license-server.sh start
Starting JetBrains License Service...
* Logging initialized @269ms 
* jetty-9.3.z-SNAPSHOT 
INFO  Config:92 - Reading classpath resource config/base.conf
INFO  Application:60 - Recources scan took 61
INFO  ApplicationContext:31 - Executing startup sequence on class com.jetbrains.ls.floating.LSApplication
INFO  Server:64 - Initializing from server-config.xml
INFO  Server:81 - server-config.xml is missing or corrupt. /root/.jb-license-server/server-config.xml (No such file or directory)
INFO  ApplicationContext:31 - Executing startup sequence on class com.jetbrains.ls.config.Config
INFO  ApplicationContext:31 - Executing startup sequence on class com.jetbrains.ls.floating.upstream.LogQueue
INFO  ApplicationContext:31 - Executing startup sequence on class com.jetbrains.ls.floating.reporting.ReportingQueue
INFO  ApplicationContext:31 - Executing startup sequence on class com.jetbrains.ls.floating.reporting.ResultStorage
MaxData ok
SimpleKey okCounterKeys ok
UsersAndIps ok
IntervalResults ok
INFO  Storage:41 - Results: 30/01/2017 12:45 - 30/01/2017 13:23. Last uploaded: null
INFO  ApplicationContext:31 - Executing startup sequence on class com.jetbrains.ls.floating.state.StallTicketRemover
* Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@49a1e95a{/,file:///opt/jetbrains/web/,AVAILABLE,localhost} 
* Started c.j.l.f.s.FakeHostsHandler@11922408{/,null,AVAILABLE} 
* Started ServerConnector@2280485f{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{hightower:8080} 
* Started @1055ms 
* JetBrains License Service is listening on {hightower:8080} 
JetBrains License Service is running
```

But I can't access the [webpage at 8080](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/license_server/register_server.html) from another computer on the LAN, in order to continue the process.

From a workstation, `01-e` on the LAN with a GUI/Ubuntu 16.04, trying to access `hightower:8080` or `http://hightower:8080/register` or `192.168.0.7:8080` or `hightower.domain.local:80801` or any combo gives me:

> Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at hightower:8080.

I can ping hightower:

```
...-01-e:~$ ping hightower
PING hightower.domain.local (192.168.0.7) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from hightower.domain.local (192.168.0.7): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.170 ms
```

Firewall isn't on, on the server `hightower`

```
admin@hightower:/opt/jetbrains$ sudo ufw status
Status: inactive
```

Stabbing in the dark to see if the page is actually being served:

```
admin@hightower:/opt/jetbrains$ wget hightower:8080
--2017-01-30 13:47:38--  http://hightower:8080/
Resolving hightower (hightower)... 127.0.1.1
Connecting to hightower (hightower)|127.0.1.1|:8080... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: http://hightower:8080/register [following]
--2017-01-30 13:47:38--  http://hightower:8080/register
Reusing existing connection to hightower:8080.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
```

So **how do I make this page visible on my LAN?**

Edit: Additional digging, it appears 8080 is only being served to localhost.  I'm guessing this is the problem.

```
admin@hightower:/opt/jetbrains$ netstat -nl
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN    
tcp6       0      0 127.0.1.1:8080          :::*                    LISTEN    
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN    
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:33247         :::*                    LISTEN
```

Edit:

```
admin@hightower:~$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   hightower

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Comment: The reason of the issue could be that the license server is setup at 127.0.1.1 instead of machine's IP.
You could have a look at the hosts file on the machine where the license server is setup, you might be able to resolve the issue there. If not, could you please post the contents of your hosts file?

Comment: added. So I just need to change the hightower IP to its LAN IP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it.  I had to run:

```
<license_server_home>/bin/license-server.sh configure --port 8080 --listen 0.0.0.0
```

instead of the suggested:

```
<license_server_home>/bin/license-server.sh configure --port 8080 --listen license-server.mydomain.com
```

I probably could have also changed /etc/hosts to read:

```
admin@hightower:~$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost
0.0.0.0     hightower
```

But it was recommended to me that this was not good practice since I only want the one port accessible.